# How can I extend redis database by redisgraph.so module?

Tags: redis

Unable to import redisgraph module *redisgraph.so* indo redis database.

1. I successfully compiled redisgraph.so from sources.
2. *redisgraph.so* execution rights are set for everyone.

I tried:

```
$ redis-cli
> shutdown ((stop redis-server))

$ redis-server --loadmodule pathto/redisgraph.so

((System replies:))

 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=2407, just started
 # Configuration loaded
 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use

$ redis-cli
> module list
(empty list or set)
> module load pathto/redisgraph.so
(error) ERR Error loading the extension. Please check the server logs.
((log file says: *no permission*))
```

redis database works fine as key-value database.
But I fail to extend it by graph functionality.

So far I am unable to drop commands like "GRAPH.QUERY" (redis replies: "unknown command").

I have no idea why redis-server seems to ignore the import command or redis-cli complains about permission rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that you already have a running process bound to the same port (probably another redis-server).

Also, you'd be better off using redisgraph with the latest Redis version (i.e. v5).

Comment: That's it! *redis-cli shutdown* does not stop the server. But  */etc/init.d/redis-server stop* does it. Now redis can import the required module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have redis managed by systemd and you could configure it as follow:
Inside

- update the supervised directive in **/etc/redis/redis.conf** to use systemd by setting ***supervised systemd***
- Creating a redis systemd file ***/etc/systemd/system/redis.service*** and set unit, service and install directive:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
> After=network.target
>
> [Service]
> User=redis
> Group=redis
> ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
> ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
> Restart=always
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

Then start redis

```
sudo systemctl start redis
sudo systemctl status redis
```

If you want redis to automatically restart when your server starts then:
Assuming all of these tests worked and that you would like to start Redis automatically when your server boots, enable the systemd service:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis
```